# Correct RESTful verb

Tags: rest

I have a resource with conditional operations:

```
/foos/{id}/authorize
/foos/{id}/cancel
```

The idea is that authorize will change the status of the resource from saved (the default) to authorized (by a third party application). The authorize could return a error from the remote part or could be authorized. Once authorized the resource could not be authorized again so this is not an action that could be called again and again.

The cancel occurs when an authorized resource is revoked. Once cancelled the resource will stay as cancelled forever.

What's the correct verb in a RESTful world for this kind of operation considering that this operation is not safe and could not be considered idempotent as a second call will return a error like "resource already cancelled" and at the same time I'm not creating a new resource, just making a status change in a known resource?

Answer (score 5):

I would use

```
DELETE /authorization/1234
```

There's a whole debate around DELETE's idempotence on previously deleted resources. See https://evertpot.com/idempotence-in-http/ and https://leedavis81.github.io/is-a-http-delete-requests-idempotent/

The bottomline here is that idempotence makes sense in a mathematical world where there's always one result, but in HTTP you get two different outcomes -- the server's response and the resource's new state. It becomes difficult identifying what is idempotent and what is not.

In such areas where the HTTP specification is not clear, I recommend pargmatism over dogmatism.

- If you really want the client to know if they deleted the resource themselves or if someone else did, then I see no problem responding 404 on a previously deleted resource.
- If you don't care, or think that it will never happen (either because there's not enough concurrent access or because all clients always do a GET moments before sending the DELETE), you can happily stick to 204 in all cases.

Comment: I'm doubting if this shouldn't be a case of `POST overloading`?

Comment: What do you mean ? POST is about creating a new resource, which one would you create in that case ?

Comment: Ah, never mind, your solution is the best idea.
I thought I recalled using POST overloading in my class REST WebServices, but I am wrong.

You should only use POST overloading in cases where PUT or DELETE are unavailable.

Comment: The server response is not relevant to whether an operation is idempotent or not, the state of the resource is the only thing that matters. From the blog post you provided: *Outcome in this sentence does not refer to the literal HTTP response, which is usually different anyway as most HTTP servers send back a Date: header.
Outcome refers to the state of the resource on the server. If I do the same DELETE more than once, the first DELETE that comes through will return a 2xx status code, and any subsequent DELETE will return a 4xx status code because the resource has already been removed.*

Comment: @AdamSiemion but you forgot to read the other blog post which says the contrary :)

Comment: @guillaume31 you got me :) the second blog does not seem to be a document that might be used to prove any point as it contains more questions than answers. However, have you reached to the last sentence in it *The status code shouldn't change between initial and subsequent requests **(I don't believe this is the case anymore - see update (1/11/13)***

Comment: Yes. He might be referring to an update in the [article](https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2013/10/28/resting-with-symfony2.html) he linked to at the beginning of his post. Some of the arguments against changing status codes along the way remain nonetheless valid IMO.

Comment: Maybe the key to this is to choose whether as a server you consider a `DELETE` on a dead resource as a mistake from the client (in which case 404 is well suited), or a legitimate request. The former is probably more justified in well-defined APIs where we don't want the client to stray away from a "scripted" Domain Application Protocol, while the latter might correspond to a looser, more liberal server.